# Error in running SSIS package through SQL Agent jobs

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I am running a SSIS package through Sql server agent jobs and I am getting below error, tried many ways to resolve it but nothing did help.

[image]

I tried running package in  64 bit and also tried to add the user that is shown in error message but no help.

Comment: Please do not use images for errors use quoted text

Comment: You're kidding, right? How can anyone figure out what the error message is from that screen shot? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75054071/edit) your question and copy-paste in the full contents of the error message as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.